Equation of a projective conic over a division ring
The equation of a conic section in homogeneous coordinates in the projective plane $\mathbb{RP}^2$ can be written as
$$
\left[\matrix{x&y&z\cr}\right]
\left[\matrix{a&b/2&d/2\cr b/2&c&e/2\cr d/2&e/2&f\cr}\right]
\left[\matrix{x\cr y\cr z\cr}\right] = 0$$
which multiplies out to
$$ax^2 + bxy + cy^2 + dxz + eyz + fz^2 = 0.$$
This is well-known enough to be covered in Wikipedia.
Consider now a non-Pappian (but still Desarguesian) plane. It is also well-known that you can coordinatize such a plane so that lines are defined by linear equations; the only catch is that all of the scalar quantities are elements of an arbitrary division ring instead of being real numbers. The fact that the plane is non-Pappian means that multiplication is not commutative in this division ring. So while you can still do analytic geometry in this system (division rings are structured enough to let you do a lot of stuff with equations) some stuff gets trickier.
I saw a claim on some random article that "For Steiner conics in desarguesian planes there always is a standard algebraic equation." That sounds great but the article does not provide a reference for that claim. I grabbed Veblen and Young's Projective Geometry, Vol 1 around page 182 where they derive the equation for a conic in a field (so they have the commutative law) while leaving out a lot of steps. Their argument goes something like this: Let $A$ and $B$ be two points on the conic, and let $m$ be the tangent line at $A$, $n$ the tangent line at $B$, and $p$ the secant line $AB$. Since $m$ and $p$ both pass through $A$ every line passing through $A$ can be written in the form $m + tp$ for some scalar $t$; likewise, every line passing through $B$ can be written as $p + sn$ for some scalar $s$. If these ``pencils of lines'' are related projectively (which is part of Steiner's definition of a conic as a set of points which are on the intersections of lines related projectively but not perspectively) then there's a way to rescale the parameters so that $s = kt$ for some scalar $k$, so now our second pencil is $p + ktn$. If we now treat $p$ as the scalar $p_xx+p_yy+p_zz$ for some point $(x,y,z)$ and with $p_x,p_y,p_z$ as the coefficients defining the line $p$, and do likewise for $m$ and $n$, then the point $(x,y,z)$ lies on the intersection of these lines iff $m + tp = 0$ and $p + ktn = 0$; we can solve for $t = -mp^{-1}$ and substitute it to get $p - kmp^{-1}n = 0$ or $p = kmp^{-1}n$. I can get this far without applying the commutative law. Veblen and Young are working in a field so they have no problem simplifying this to $p^2 = kmn$, where again $p$, $m$, and $n$ are all linear combinations of $x$,$y$, and $z$ so this equation is clearly quadratic in those variables; algebra will get you to the traditional standard form of a conic.
My question is this: Can I go any farther without commutativity? To be clear, where I've stopped is $p = kmp^{-1}n$, and if I expand it out I get the following general equation of a conic:
$$p_xx+p_yy+p_zz = k(m_xx+m_yy+m_zz)(p_xx+p_yy+p_zz)^{-1}(n_xx+n_yy+n_zz).$$ Is this the "standard algebraic equation" referenced by the article above? I can make it look more tantalizing as $pn^{-1}p=km$ (that $p$ really wants to be squared!) but this doesn't seem to buy me anything. So am I stuck at this point, or would a clever technique take me farther?
While I'm here I'd like to tack on a reference request: I would be interested in any good books or long articles about conic sections in noncommutative division rings.
